# Iterate through directories recursively in PHP

Tags: php

When I upload photos to my web server I try to split up the photos into several folders so that I won't have so many photos in 1 single folder.

for example inside a class:

```
$filename = hash('crc32b', mt_rand());
$img_dir = UPLOAD_DIR.DS.'img'.DS.$filename[0].$filename[1].DS.$filename[2].$filename[3].DS.$filename[4].$filename[5];
```

`DS` is a short version of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

This could create directories like these:

```
public_html\assets\upload\img\25\55\8b
public_html\assets\upload\img\00\8c\2a
```

if file does not exist and there are no directories like that already

```
$img_path = $img_dir.DS.$filename.'.jpg';

if (!file_exists($img_path) && !is_dir($img_dir)) {
    $mode = 0755;
    mkdir($img_dir, $mode, true);

    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR, $mode);
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR.DS.'img', $mode);
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR.DS.'img'.DS.$filename[0].$filename[1], $mode);
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR.DS.'img'.DS.$filename[0].$filename[1].DS.$filename[2].$filename[3], $mode);
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR.DS.'img'.DS.$filename[0].$filename[1].DS.$filename[2].$filename[3].DS.$filename[4].$filename[5], $mode);
}
```

I wan't all folders to be 755, how can do that recursively?

EDIT:

Also why do I get `493` as output when I do `echo $mode;` or `echo 0755;` ?

Comment: As for your edit, `0755` is an octal which in decimal is `493`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the shell, and assuming the OS is Linux, I'd go with:

```
system('chmod -R ' . escapeshellarg(UPLOAD_DIR));
```

As for your edit, `0755` is an octal which in decimal is `493`.

EDIT: you can also try this function, beware that `$path` should be the full path to a single file, or the path to a directory **without trailing slash**

```
function chmod_recursive($path, $mode) {
    if(is_dir($path)) {
        foreach(glob("$path/*") as $file) {
            chmod_recursive($file, $mode);
        }
    }
    else if(is_file($path)) {
        chmod($path, $mode);
    }
}
```

calling it like this:

```
chmod_recursive(UPLOAD_DIR, 0755);
```

Comment: I guess you answered my question since I asked for a recursive method. But now that I think about it, since I create 3 directories every time someone uploads a photo I might end up with 16^6 = 16777216 directories in the end, I don't think I should be doing recursive anything from the UPLOAD_DIR and downwards. I was thinking from the deepest DIR and upwards to UPLOAD_DIR. Thanks anyways. I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the directories starting at  the root:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator(UPLOAD_DIR) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    chmod($fileInfo->getFilename(), $mode);
}
```

taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: This only gave me the img folder, and not the whole level of directories.